How much electricity do rubber shoe soles conduct?
When working with high voltage, I heard that you shouldn't provide a path from the current source to the ground using your body or you'll get shocked. Is that also true if you're wearing shoes? There is no perfect insulator in the world, so rubber should conduct electricity. At what point will you get shocked if you wear shoes?

Rubber-soled shoes can reduce the risk of electric shock to some extent because they offer higher resistance compared to bare skin.Different rubbers have different resistances. High-quality, thick rubber soles provide better insulation.
At high voltages, even small amounts of current can be dangerous. The higher the voltage, the more critical the quality of the insulation.

Shocked implies a breakdown threshold either by going through an insulator or along the surface (creepage). Normally this occurs by surface contamination ( moisture & ionic particles).

Is that also true if you're wearing shoes?

That is possible yes. There are many scenarios.
Rubber car tires are even better insulators because they have been processed with typ. 1GV e-beams for cross-link structural improvements, which raises the breakdown voltage unless later contaminated on the surface. Many videos exist to show a car hit by lightning protecting the passengers inside, acting like a Faraday cage. However, the charge on your body or car can still be a risk if discharged by a person near when gasoline vapours.
Almost all shoes will be too high resistance to meet the requirements of ESD/EOS safety. The exception might be sweaty leather-soled shoes.  However, this does not test the breakdown voltage limit. Even rubber boots if damp inside and out are not safe, if there is HV in the area. (e.g. dirty AC electric lawnmower motor, power tools etc.

At what point will you get shocked if you wear shoes?

This depends on the scenario. (breakdown or leakage)

Exceeds breakdown voltage of insulation  ( Insulators have 5 to 10x more protection to 1us impulses than RMS voltage due to the ionization time ) Grid components are rated by Basic Insulation Level xxx which means the number of kV it can withstand to a 1.2/8us HV impulse.  Shoes are not rated unless designated safety shoes for line workers.

Leakage is common and tested on all PE grounded appliances. Laptop chargers are generally not PE grounded yet still have common mode leakage capacitance and voltage potential. You would not feel any current ( > 50 uA) wearing rubber-soled shoes touched a charged laptop, but you could without shoes over grass or a humid carpet.


However, wearing neoprene-soled shoes over old nylon (non-dissipative) carpet you can easily build up 20kV and feel the shock touching a door knob. You can calibrate the voltage by touching the knob with a wire and measuring the wire gap at ~ 1kV/mm for a sharp point. (3kV/mm between smooth flat surfaces).
This depends on the capacitance ratio and breakdown voltage or V/mm E field stress level.  You can measure steady leakage with an AC current meter for < = 100 uA or voltage with a 10Meg DMM.  Most likely you feel nothing but if you want to calibrate your senses with say 100x more sensitivity from a small sensitive area, try the tip of knee cap or wrist lightly to the laptop corner while one finger is on a stove ground or equiv. That is not a severe shock, but an introduction to normal Trafo leakage currents on RF SMPS considered safe.
Do not try this, if you do not understand my directions or trust your equipment.
E-beam process for tires. Ref
Effects of E-beam/ or cross-link process on plastic  and Rubber  and more

Do the car tyres really take any part in the protection of car occupants from lightning? Wouldn't the Faraday cage effect be the same if the car was not on tyres? I'm thinking that that is not a good example. Also, car tyres have steel belts in them, and I thought they were vulcanised (a heating process), not subjected to electric fields.

Yes but current must result in low V on chassis which only occurs from distributed leakage to air/floor.  Not true they are pre-vulcanized with a 1GV e-beam which also zaps contaminants and hardens flat strips before sulphur-rubber heat-vulcanizing the tread. https://www.nhv.jp/en/eb/crosslink/tirerubber.html

I will append research results to support the insulation effects of cross-link process

what is an "1GV e-beam"? and: in your answe, you say "1GV electric fields", but a field strength is not given by giving the voltage (I'd also have serious doubts about you technologically using a gigavolt potential difference on solid state matter, but that's a different thing.)

1GV is a nominal emitter voltage.  Products range below and up to 5GV.  I imagine this becomes a current source to insulative particles between carbon black.  The e-field on nano-particles is not 1GV due to displacement. TY for your comments.   https://www.nhv.jp/en/products/

I edited it to say e-beam voltage

Data point: Cars without static grounding straps build up an unpleasant charge in warm dry conditions. Stepping to ground while touching the car body can be painful.  Hopping clear so not to make body-ground contact simultaneously helps.
|| N people holding hands and shuffling across a nylon carpet build up (maybe) N times the charge, Certainly much more than one person for say 6 people in the string. Touching a person, or filing cabinet with a finger causes a painful shock for source and destination (if a person_) and a lesser shock at each hand holding link. Ask me how I know :-)

1 GeV electron beam won't deposit much energy in the item because the electrons would go right thru - linked page of accelerators suggest 5 MeV election beam for rubber tyre crosslinking

Dry winters, static generating nylon carpets, neoprene, soled shoes can create the highest voltage I have seen. These are painless with a 5cm arc slowly discharged with a key ( low skin current density), unlike the abrupt discharge to a tiny spot of a fingertip. This suggests that boot insulation must not be just a great insulator but also a poor triboelectric generator.

It's not easy to give a concrete answer unless you specify all the variables involved: shoe type, sole material, humidity of air, humidity of shoe, sock, the surface you're standing on, etc.
An insulator has, by definition high resistivity. According to wikipedia, "hard rubber" has a resistivity of 10^13 Ω·m at 20 °C. According to OSHA, an electric shock of 1..5 mA is not dangerous but perceptible. Initially that should indicate >~10^6 V·mm across you and the shoe, the shoe sole being the dominating resistance - should make a perceptible shock.
That being said, insulators undergo breakdown at a certain voltage per length, after which the insulating properties break down and the conductivity increases drastically. Wikipedia is back to the rescue with ballpark numbers: 15..26 MV/m for neoprene rubber. Let's say a shoe sole is 1 cm thick. Breakdown occurs at a few hundred kV, so a voltage in the range ~100 kV to 10 MV should be pretty unpleasant.
The caveat for that 'back of the envelope' magnitude estimation is that the rubber is actually the dominating resistance. Imagine that you're barefoot on a practically infinite sheet of rubber.

"Initially that should indicate >~10^6 V·mm across you and the shoe, the shoe sole being the dominating resistance - should make a perceptible shock." Don't understand that sentence, I'm afraid, needs rewording.

Given a choice between flipping the breaker and wearing rubber soled shoes- I vote for the flipped breaker. Followed by a check with a neon-bulb tester.

@Fred, that's a comment to post on the question instead, not this one answer. Otherwise, a lot of people are going to miss it.

@TonyM Thanks for the cleanup. I'll take a look at that sentence later.

You're welcome, glad you saw it as helpful - answer upvoted.

I just want to mention the capacitance to earth a person may have. A typical value for me is 100-200 pF. So at the moment of contact to a HV-DC source the charge current can be shocking, even with good rubber shoes. This is not dangerous, but you may feel more awake and refreshed afterwards.
My impedance at 50 Hz AC would be between 16 and 32 MΩ, independent of the isolation resistance the shoes may have.
If you come close to a very old 15 kHz, 25 kV AC TV line transformer output, it may quickly burn a tiny hole in your finger, even if you hang in mid air. This is quite impressive.

How long is a string?
For straight up resistance of shoes and boots, both plastic and rubber has naturally high volume resistivty. However, black soles are preferred in most parts of the world and the cheapest way to make both plastic and rubber black is “carbon black”, i.e. finely milled carbon, which is conductive.
Your average cotton socks and regular shoes with black soles will give you about 10 MΩ, but the variance depending on exact shoes and level of sweat is very high. White rubber boots with white soles will put you in the GΩ range.
ESD shoes take this to another level by making sure the resitivity is low, but requires socks to match. Cotton and wool conducts fairly well. White nylon much less.
As stated above by Jens, at AC, the capacitance though the shoes could dominate over resistance.

Someone flagged this answer. I declined the flag. The answer is shorter than ideal, BUT the information in it looks useful. White gumboots do not contain carbon filler so have higher voltage ratings.

@RussellMcMahon Oh. I can expand it a bit for future readers.

One thing that should be obvious is that no matter what resistance (say) 1cm of rubber sole gives you, if you go over 30kV there is a good chance of flashover from your toes.
Also, if you have even a pinprick hole in the sole you are going to be in big trouble. This is especially likely when it comes to gloves.
One of the many reasons I never work with high voltage high current sources.
One mistake and you are dead or worse, and given the number of mains shocks I have had the writing is on the wall.
